# How do I make it so My GUI can send multiple messages to my socket server?

Tags: sockets, user-interface, customtkinter

So I'm having trouble getting threaded it to work with our GUI. Our client is able to send multiple messages in a succession without having to wait for a response, but the GUI just hasn't been able to, I've tried to use threading, bit it doesn't seem to work with customTkinter so how could I do this? (GUI code has been reverted back to before we tried to use threading)

I tried to put threading code in the send_message function and I'm stuck, not sure how I can progress and allow for our server socket to receive multiple messages from the GUI. This is the GUI's code

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import socket
import threading


SERVER_ADDRESS = '10.0.36.9'
SERVER_PORT = 1234

chat = ctk.CTk()
chat.geometry('900x600')
ctk.set_appearance_mode('light')


chat.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
chat.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
chat.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

chat.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
chat.rowconfigure(1, weight=2)
chat.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
chat.rowconfigure(3, weight=0)






def send_message():
    message = message_entry.get()

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT))
    client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    response = client_socket.recv(1234).decode('utf-8')

    return response

def GUI():
    chat.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    chat.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    chat.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    chat.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
    chat.rowconfigure(1, weight=2)
    chat.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    chat.rowconfigure(3, weight=0)

    send_button = ctk.CTkButton(chat, text="send", command=send_message, hover=True, width=100)
    send_button.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew")

    message_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(master=chat, placeholder_text="Message Here...", width=300)
    message_entry.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky="ew", pady=20)

while True:
    # insert code for receiving new network messages
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.listen(5)
    chat.update_idletasks()
    chat.update()
# chat.mainloop()
```

Comment: As _the GUI_ is a client, why do you have _`server_socket`_ in _the GUI's code_?

Comment: oh thank you, I didn't realise I did that, I was supposed to get it from the client code i have.